# How to change http.sys web server response when maxconnection limit reached

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpsys

We are using http sys web server to host web api service. Business requires to limit maximum number of concurrent connections. MaxConnections configuration property used for that purpose:

```
services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxConnections = Configuration.GetValue<long?>("MaxConnections");
});
```

But in case when concurrent connection limit reached all new connections got dropped on a socket level. Is it possible to change this behaviour so server accepts the request and returns 4xx or 5xx response to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to find a solution: there is [Http503Verbosity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.httpsysoptions.http503verbosity?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property in options. By default it is set to [Http503VerbosityLevel.Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.http503verbositylevel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but if to change it to Http503VerbosityLevel .Limited or Http503VerbosityLevel.Full 503 response will be returned for requests above limit. So my code looks like this now:

```
        services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MaxConnections = Configuration.GetValue<long?>("MaxConnections");
            options.Http503Verbosity = Http503VerbosityLevel.Full;
        });
```